# Proof of Existence of Complete Field with Dense Subfield

Tags: metric-spaces, absolute-value

First, the question at hand:

Prove there exists a field $E$ which contains $F$ as a subfield, such that E has an absolute value extending the absolute value on $F$, such that $F$ is dense in $E$, and $E$ is complete.

Now here we use the field definition for an absolute value and we say a field is **complete** if every Cauchy sequence in $F$ defined on this absolute value converges to some value in $F$. Furthermore, we define $F$ to be **dense** in $E$ if given $\epsilon>0$, and an element $\alpha\in$E, there exists $a\in F$ such that $|\alpha-a|<\epsilon$.

I already know how to prove that for a field $F$ with an absolute value defined on it, the factor(quotient) ring of Cauchy sequences mod the null sequences is a field $E$ itself, and that the absolute value of $F$ can be extended to this field $E$, and indeed that this field $E$ is complete. Does this help in the question?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are there any examples of this which come to your mind? It seems the question wants you to give an example of one (and prove that it is an example).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Take $E = \mathbb{R}$ and $F = \mathbb{Q}$, with the typical absolute value. It is up to you to show that this is such an example.

Remark: More generally one can take the "completion" of a field with an absolute value equipped, which would have all of these desired properties more or less by definition. As Dietrich Burde notes, $\mathbb{Q}_p$, the field of $p$-adic numbers, is the "completion" of $\mathbb{Q}$ with the $p$-adic absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main examples. First, $(\mathbb{Q},|\cdot|_{\infty})$ together with the Archimedean absolute value. It is not complete with respect to the induced metric. The completion of this valued field is $(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|_{\infty})$. Of course, $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Secondly, $(\mathbb{Q},|\cdot|_{p})$ together with the non-Archimedean $p$-adic absolute value. The completion of this valued field is $(\mathbb{Q}_p,|\cdot|_{p})$. Again, $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{Q}_p$.